# Shouldn't questions with 0 answers or small amount of views be accentuated more?

Tags: feature-request, public-beta, unanswered-questions

Maybe have the colour of the views number in red if there are no answers or something like that.

As it is now, there is some difficulty distinguishing the ones without any views from the ones that do have views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ChrisF said, once a theme is applied, questions with 0 answers should appear slightly different. As for now, you can still browse the "unanswered questions" by following the link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: ok, so things like this one will be addressed then. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just an effect of the "sketchy" nature of the Beta theme.

If you check out Stack Overflow or Super User questions with no answers are easily spotted.